# Sklearn Mean Absolute Error with X and Y From Rows

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics

I tried to do Mean Absolute Error from Sklearn with this dataset

| Name | Jan Qty | Feb Qty | Mar Qty | Jan Fcst | Feb Fcst | Mar Fcst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | 10 | 5 | 23 | 7 | 4 | 24 |
| Apple | 5 | 3 | 32 | 8 | 7 | 17 |

I want to create New Column named **MAE** with `sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error` in it with

`y_true = Jan Qty, Feb Qty, and Mar Qty`

`y_pred = Jan Fcst, Feb Fcst, and Mar Fcst`

so I can get mean absolute error of Banana and Apple

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Just to be sure I assume you're using pandas? It would be nice if you showed what you tried and why it doesn't work. If you have a doubt you can always check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: mean_absolute_error(x.filter(regex='Qty'), x.filter(regex='Fcst')), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
0    1.666667
1    7.333333
dtype: float64
```